# Mapping Alt + left|right to move tabs

Tags: vim

Ideally, I'd like `<A-left>` to execute `:tabmove -1` and `<A-right>` to execute `:tabmove +1`. However, when I put

```
nnoremap <A-left> :tabmove -1<cr>
nnoremap <A-right> :tabmove +1<cr>
```

in my .vimrc and try  or , vim beeps and moves my cursor one character over in the direction I pressed. However, typing `:tabmove -1<cr>` directly into command mode gives the desired effect. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce the desired effect using `:tabmove -1<cr>`, I get E488, however, try changing `<A-left>` to `<esc><left>` and see if that works for you.  Same with `<A-right>`.

Comment: Thanks @RandyMorris, Ingo below suggests a similar workaround.

Comment: It works with
`nnoremap <M-left> :tabmove -1<cr>`.
I'm using vim 9.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to the way that the keyboard input is handled internally, this unfortunately isn't possible today in most terminals, but should work in GVIM. Some key combinations, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + non-alphabetic cannot be mapped, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + letter vs. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + letter cannot be distinguished. This is a known pain point, and the subject of various discussions on vim_dev and the #vim IRC channel.

As a workaround, use different keys, e.g. `<Leader><Left>` / `<Leader><Right>`.

Answer (score 21):

Start by viewing the key code your terminal is sending to vim:

```
$ sed -n l
^[[1;9D
```

In the above example, i ran the sed command and pressed <kbd>Alt + Left</kbd>.

The `^[[1;9D` is the escaped sequence being sent to vim, so we can user that for our mapping.

Add this to your .vimrc

```
map <Esc>[1;9D :tabn<CR>
```

Now we can cycle through vim tabs by using <kbd>Alt + Left</kbd>

Comment: This is actually the right answer that works. I wonder why it is not selected as answer.

Comment: What about Alt + Right?

Comment: run `sed -n l` and press `right` on your keyboard, what gets printed?

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me to remap Alt key among all the various posts here, thanks a lot!